# Java's DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain equivalent in Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a service that needs to authenticate either 1. by getting the credentials from ec2 instance metadata 2. or by using sts

In java I'm using the `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` which works fine. Is there a equivalent in python's boto3?

At the moment if I'm connecting through ec2 metadata i'm using:

```
    provider = InstanceMetadataProvider(iam_role_fetcher=InstanceMetadataFetcher(timeout=1000, num_attempts=2))
    creds = provider.load()

    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=creds.access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=creds.secret_key,
        aws_session_token=creds.token
    )
```

but if I use sts I change it to:

```
    sts = boto3.client('sts')
    response = sts.assume_role(
        RoleArn='aws:arn:iam::account_id:role/role-that-allows-s3-access',
        RoleSessionName='my-random-session-name',
        DurationSeconds=2000  # how many seconds these credentials will work
    )

    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken']
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `InstanceMetadataProvider` and explicitly set credetnails in your `client`. boto3 by default works like `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` as explained in [Configuring credentials](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#configuring-credentials).

So if you, for example, what to use s3 on the instance, you do:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
```

This will **automatically** get credentials from the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

sts_client = boto3.client("sts")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).